# emberjs : add active css class to link based on current route

Tags: ember.js

I am using Ember version 1.8 . Does anyone know how to automatically highlight menu link when user is in that route. Plese help. I saw few Stack overflow posts on doing it. but they looks old and is not working for me

I have the following menu in handlebars template

```
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li>
                {{#link-to 'posts'}}Posts{{/link-to}}
                </li>
                <li>
                {{#link-to 'comments'}}Comments{{/link-to}}
                </li>
            </ul>
```

router.js looks like

```
   this.resource('post', { path: 'posts/:post_id'},function(){
            this.resource('comments', { path: '/comments' });

    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ember automatically adds a class of `active` to a routed currently being visited. You can define what that should look like in css, for example:

```
.active {
  background: yellow;
}
```

The rest just works...

See a working demo [here](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/riwaci/1/edit?html,css,js,output)

Comment: Kalman, thats what i thought. but for some reason it is not working for me. let me check my code again

Comment: kalman, look like the jsbin code is adding active class to <a> tag not to <li>. is there any way to add it to <li>?

Comment: linkt-to takes a tagName as an argument, so you can do something like this `{{#link-to 'posts' tagName='li'}}Posts{{/link-to}}` see the following http://emberjs.jsbin.com/riwaci/2/edit?html,css,js,output

Comment: Did some more research see the edited jsbin http://emberjs.jsbin.com/riwaci/3/edit https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/pull/1849